# Work with XDocument. C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm try to use:

```
new XElement("sometag", XElement.Parse(someText));
```

I don't know value of someText, but i want to get:

```
<sometag>
    qwert <tag>qwe</tag> qwerty
</sometag>
```

if

```
someText = "qwert <tag>qwe<tag> qwerty";
```

or

```
<sometag>
    qwert qwe qwerty
</sometag>
```

if

```
someText = "qwert qwe qwerty";
```

How can this be implemented?

Comment: it's horribly unclear what you are asking for

Comment: Your first example is not valid xml so that would not be possible.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko The end result is valid, it's [mixed content](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp).  How to parse it is a little trickier...

Comment: @CharlesMager, I stand corrected, whether this works with XDocument I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse a fragment containing any `XNode` rather than an `XElement`.  There's no obvious way to do this.  Using some lower-level XML APIs you can read each node using something like this:

```
const string someText = "qwert <tag>qwe</tag> qwerty";

var element = new XElement("sometag");

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};

using (var sr = new StringReader(someText))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
{
    xr.MoveToContent();

    while (!xr.EOF)
    {
        var node = XNode.ReadFrom(xr);   
        element.Add(node);
    }
}
```

The resulting XML is:

```
<sometag>qwert <tag>qwe</tag> qwerty</sometag>
```

Comment: Thank you.

Sorry for my English.